# My screensaver comes on after 1 minute and I can't stop it without tapping a key or moving the mouse

Tags: macos, screensaver

No matter how I change my settings, my iMac Retina's monitor switches over to the screensaver after only one minute of inactivity. Quite a bother when I'm trying to read something. This continued after I upped to OS 10.12.6. I've zapped PRAM and repaired permissions and this, that, and the other but it won't stop doing this. I've looked on the web for answers but can't find any others suffering this malady. Ideas?

Comment: What do the commands `defaults read com.apple.screensaver idleTime` and `defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime` return?

Comment: have you tried setting it to never come on?